# How can I make it show 10,11,12,13.... instead of ... in javafx.I have try to use all those setPrefWidth, maxSize but cannot work

Tags: java, css, user-interface, button, javafx

```
private HBox buttonBar;
    private ScrollPane questionScroll;
    private ArrayList<Button> btnList = new ArrayList<>();

    public QuestionNavigationBar(int quesNo) {
        questionScroll = new ScrollPane();
        questionScroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        buttonBar = new HBox();
        init(quesNo);

        questionScroll.setFitToWidth(true);
        questionScroll.setContent(buttonBar);
        questionScroll.setPrefWidth(400);
        buttonBar.setStyle("-fx-border-color:cyan; -fx-border-width: 5;");
        buttonBar.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 20, 0));
    }

    //create buttons for each map entry
    public void init(int quesNo) {
        int counter = 1;
        while (counter <= quesNo) {
            Button btnTmp = new Button(Integer.toString(counter));
            btnTmp.setMaxSize(50, 50);
            btnTmp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; ");
            buttonBar.getChildren().add(btnTmp);
            getBtnList().add(btnTmp);
            counter++;
        }

    }
```

This is my output, so the button couldn't show a two-digit integer.I have try to use all those setPrefWidth, maxSize but cannot work.

[image: Ouput]

Comment: don't hard-code sizing hints

Answer (score 1):

The labels will elide (truncate text with dots) if there is not enough room to display the text.

If you wish to prevent that from happening, set the min size to the preferred size.

```
button.setMinSize(
     Region.USE_PREF_SIZE,
     Region.USE_PREF_SIZE
);
```

See javadoc: [USE_PREF_SIZE](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#USE_PREF_SIZE).

Study: [Oracle’s layout tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html).

Also, ensure the preferred size of the button is not set explicitly, so that the layout can appropriately calculate it, and don’t set the max size to a value less than the min size.